# Get state of MATLAB GUI radiobuttons?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have two radio buttons in my interface. I also have some pushbuttons. When ever I click a pushbutton I want it to call a function according to the selected radio button.

I tried adding the function given below

```
function rotation_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)]
Tag = get(hObject, 'Tag'); 
disp(Tag);
```

But nothing is coming up when I change the selection. I want to know whether there is any mistake in the way I implemented the  code or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I need more information. How did you set up the callback? What does get(hObject) give you? Why is there a square bracket at the end of the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use radiobuttons you might want to regroup them in [button groups](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html), then it's quite easy to play with radio buttons, and you make sure that only 1 radio button per group gets selected at any time.

For radio buttons in button groups, you want to use the following:

```
get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag')
```

to get the tag of the new value just being selected. You can also use OldValue as well if you want.

In the callback of your pushbutton, you can query whether a radio button is activated with its 'value', i.e. 1 if it is selected.

```
StateRadioButton = get(handles.RadioButton1,'Value'); %assuming the tag is "RadioButton1".
```

The hObject property is particular for the specific callback in which it is used, otherwise you need to use the handles structure to access elements from other functions.

Comment: My pleasure! Glad to help again :)